# Streaming live video to websites?

Tags: web-server, streaming-video, webcam, headless

A little flavor text: My wife and I are having our baby in Taiwan, and we want to use a camera, such that my family and friends can go to a website, fill in a password, and see a live stream of the baby sleeping at certain times.

I have a Raspberry pi running linux headlessly, and have tried using the motion application -- but this only allows me to view about 1 frame per second locally, from within my own router. What I want is to have someone go to www.mywebsite.com/babycam and see the video stream. It isn't important for people to be able to hear our audio, but it might be nice later, when I decide to use this as a baby monitor. The goal is for the video broadcast to start when I turn the pi's power on at a certain time. I don't particularly care if there's a short delay before the video actually reaches the web, but I'd like the video viewed on the website to have a watchable framerate (>15 fps) and to be continuous. So far I'm trying to follow the tutorial [over here about websockets] (http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets), but I am stuck at the line of code here:

> node stream-server.js yourpassword

And I think I either need advice on how to continue in the tutorial, or I need something much simpler. Also, the method I am following does not give audio.

If you were just getting started with Linux, and really just wanted to set this up quickly before the baby was born, what would you do? Do you know of any instructions to follow?

Comment: What else have you tried? Are you familiar with port forwarding? I've created a system similar to what you have described and would be happy to help. Just need more information on your progress thus far.

Comment: Hi! I'll edit my question. I've been trying to follow this tutorial, but it's a bit beyond me at the moment, a I have no idea how nodejs is supposed to work, and I'm a bit stuck following the command......

node stream-server.js yourpassword

......from the tutorial:

http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets.......

and I am thinking that what I need is a simpler solution, or a more detailed set of instructions on how to set this up. Do you know of any?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I don't really have any experience with port forwarding, but I would be very excited to receive some help! Thanks a bunch, sir!

Comment: Follow this link:
    http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-build-and-run-mjpg-streamer-on-the-raspberry-pi

After you run through the steps in the link, comment to let me know and I can help you through the configuration details to allow remote access to the feed.

Comment: Super! Will do.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](http://zacharybears.com/low-latency-raspberry-pi-video-streaming/). Even I am planning to use it in my project. Haven't tested it yet. Have you found any other way @Catlard ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to raspberrypi.SE. Even though this might be an answer to the question, it would be beneficial if you would include the most important part here, in your answer, if for no other reason than to prevent link rot. Thank you.

Comment: Hey, I sort of gave up -- I guess I'd have ot use this method in combination with an external IP in order to get things going. I'll try it out. Thanks!